# iPhone UITableViewCell slow performance

Tags: performance, uitableview, custom-cell

I just wrote a small application that read from a site feed and display in UITableViewCell. I am using custom view cell and my UITableView is screwed in scrolling like it is not very smooth in scrolling upside down. Any idea? Here's the code for my UITableViewCell,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //MiceAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (MiceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(dataArray != nil) {
        //  
        //NSArray *promoArray = (NSArray *) promotions;
        NSDictionary *datadict = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *url = [datadict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"];
        NSString *title = [datadict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *description = [datadict objectForKey:@"description"];

        NSString *newAddressPartOfURL = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

        //NSLog([url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

        NSURLResponse *urlResponse;

        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newAddressPartOfURL]] returningResponse:&urlResponse error:nil];

        // Configure the cell.
        UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        //  NSLog(@"%i",[imageView.image topCapHeight]);
        cell.title.text = title;
        cell.description.text = description;
        cell.image.image = urlImage;
        [urlImage release];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing synchronous downloads as your cells are being drawn is definitely going to cause some unsmooth scrolling.  You could try to replace those with [asynchronous](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) calls, and filling in the data with a generic object while the download is happening.  When the download completes, then call reloadData on your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

afaik the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method is called as cells get flush etc. Build your data / do the requests on init, not in the cell creation!